# Aloha Editor not reading data from db file

Tags: aloha-editor

I managed to get [Aloha editor][1] working with SQLite database file without problem on one website so I thougnt I will copy all the files to get the other website work too but I found the problems which I cannot resolve myself. Problems might be leated to each other, not sure.

Problem 1:
I see editing textarea with "Click to edit me." Whatever I type there goes to db.sqlite file as I can see data by sqlitebrowser.exe. But if I refresh page I still see "Click to edit me."

Problem 2:
When I edit Page and press F5 (refresh) page shows as usual but cannot edit it anymore (no yellow highlights)
But when I press Ctl+F5 that I can edit the page (of course as per problem 1 still is just "Click to edit me.")

Thats how I load JS (same order):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="alohaeditor/aloha/lib/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aloha-config.js"></script>

<?php if ($login->isLoggedIn() && !empty($_SESSION['settings_users_name'])){?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="alohaeditor/aloha/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,common/format,common/highlighteditables,common/link,common/characterpicker,common/undo"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="aloha-save.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        Aloha.ready( function() {
          Aloha.jQuery('.editable').aloha();
        });
   </script>
<?}?>
```

It's already 5h like I'm trying to work out how to solve that.
Can someone please point me out how to check whats wrong? (maybe how to use firebug in this case to trace problem?)
      [1]: http://aloha-editor.org/

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery? Has the editable area an ID?

Comment: Sorry jQuery is also there just before require.js and the editable area looks like this: `<div class="editable" id="article"><?=getAlohaContent('article')?></div>` BTW I 'm using your script from : [link] https://gist.github.com/1448270

Comment: I know now where the problem is but not sure yet how to solve it.

Comment: I know now where the problem is but not sure yet how to solve it. The problem is that in file `aloha-save.js` there is `var pageId = window.location.pathname;` but in `lib.php` there is `$pageId = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];`. My links looks like: `index.php?v=about-us`

Comment: yep. index.php?v=about-us is the problem -- this was not tested / intended to be used for that demo.
you'll need to update the code so that it will use eg just the v= value (sharing the result would be fine ;)